# How to change text size in java file?

Tags: android

How to change text size in java file?
Please answer to my question.Thankyou

Xml file:

```
<TextView
                android:id="@+id/txt1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="10dp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="@string/a"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:textDirection="rtl"
                android:textSize="40dp" />
```

Comment: Suggestion: You'll get more views/help if you mention Android in your subject line in addition to the tag. And, since you clearly are setting the textsize in the xml you provide, can you tell us what is NOT working? Is it that you want to change the textsize on the fly programatically?

Answer (score 2):

Here i have the 2 solutions:

```
  1. 
   tv.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 25); //dip or sp etc as you need

        OR
   2.

  txt1.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_PX, 
                   getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.result_font));
```

Thanks a lot

Comment: I write this line and i give crash

Comment: it's working, i have tried right now. try the first solution which is simple as possible.

Answer (score 1):

Try like this:

```
txt1.setTextSize(15);
```

Comment: I write this line and i give crash

Comment: I can't see from this log, maybe you made mistake when you init the text view.

Comment: how to add init to textview?

Comment: copy the java code so i can see whaat are you doing

Answer (score 0):

Use setTextSize() to set values in dp.

Comment: I write this line and i give crash